# Express with API - Can't access inner JSON Object

Tags: express, request, riot-games-api

Here's code from the Riot Developer API.

I want to log the id from the body object in the console.

```
app.get('/hallo', function(req, res) {
var data = {};
var summoner = "dyrus";
var apikey = "xxxxxxxx";
var URL = "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by- 
name/Teemo?api_key=" + apikey;
var URL2 = "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by- 
name/" + summoner +"?api_key=" + apikey;

request(URL, function (err, data) {
  console.log(data.body);
 })
})
```

Writing:

```
console.log(data.body)
```

Gives me back:

```
"{"id":34080052,"accountId":37712662,"name":"Teemo","profileIconId":0,"revisionDate":1495767212000,"summonerLevel":6}"
```

How can I access the `id` field in the object body?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(data.body).id` ?

Comment: Ty man, I feel not smart right now... it worked!

Comment: Glad if it helped, sometimes we get stuck on simple problems. I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can access it this way:

`JSON.parse(data.body).id`